# Help! A black bar appears and disappears whenever mouse is used

Tags: interface

When i opened the new Blender version 2.78c, i started noticing a black bar or shape which was appearing and disappearing whenever i moved the mouse. Not able to work on blender because it is very irritating. No idea what is causing the problem. Please help out asap.

Comment: probably a graphics driver issue. What are your specs. Are you using PC or Laptop. Linux, Windows or OS X?

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I am using laptop. My Specs are: Intel I-3,8 gb ram, AMD Radeon R5 M230 and an Intel on board graphics. All other editing apps are working perfectly..

Comment: Blender and OpenCL (AMD Cards) are known to have issues in the past. Those the support is becoming better they still have to quite a lot of problems. My advice: reinstall Blender, make sure graphics drivers are up to date and if that doesn't work try maybe reinstalling the graphic drivers.

Comment: I used blender earlier but didn't have this problem.. so i am thinking downgrading the version. Hope it solves